# Here's a puzzler: __set($value, $name) not called when a setter matching $obj->$key exists, but is called when it doesn't

Tags: php, magic-methods

Here's the context:

```
$values = $form->getValues();
foreach($values as $key=>$value) {         
$obj->{$key} = $value;
}
```

If `$key` is a valid key, `__set($name, $value)` is not called.  If `$key` is not a valid key, it is.  Here's what my set looks like:

```
public function __set($name, $value) {
    $method = 'set' . ucfirst($name);
    if(method_exists($method)) {
        $this->$method($value);
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException('Attempt to access a non-existant property with method ' . $method);
    }
}
```

In the object to which the `__set($name, $value)` method belongs, all properties are private and underscored.  So for key 'name' there would be the following:

```
private $_name;

public function setName($name) {
    $this->_name = $name; 
    return $this; 
}
```

I know that it isn't called because I tried inserting an exception just after the `$method = 'set' . ucfirst($name);`.  That exception was hit when `$name` did not reference a valid setter, but was not hit when it didn't.  It should have been hit every time.  Anyone have any clue what's happening here?

Comment: +1 for using Fluent Interface and throwing a semantically correct PHP exception where appropriate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is by design. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)

> __set() is run when writing data to inaccessible properties.

If you have `public` properties matching `$key`, they will be set because they are *accessible*.

Also, your use of [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) is incorrect. It should be

```
if (method_exists($this, $method))
```

Comment: You misunderstand.  The properties are all private and are $_{key}.  The setters are 'set' . ucfirst($key).  There is nothing that exactly matches $key.  But thank you for catching my error with method_exists.  It doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: @DanielBingham You will have to clarify what you mean by "valid key" then.

Comment: @Phil If there is a matching setter method. I edited the body and title, should make more sense now. Fixing method_exists fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

That's documented behavior; it's how __set() actually works: [documentation here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members).